# php curl request with proxy to https links

Tags: php, curl, https, proxy, php-curl

hi im trying to use proxy (http protocol) in curl to connect to websites that use **https**, but no luck it return : `Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT`
i tried to add the flowing : ,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
```

here is my code :

```
$proxy_ip = //proxy ip;
$proxy_port = //proxy port;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com');\\ example
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
echo $result;
```

the proxy works fine on `postman` so i know for sure that the proxy that im using is live 
and it don't need authentication

Comment: It's probably not desired to downgrade HTTPS to HTTP?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz but it worked with postman application